# How to calculate cpu usage in Prometheus Postgres exporter?

Tags: postgresql, prometheus

We want to get the CPU usage of PostgreSQL through [postgres_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter) in Prometheus.

There are three CPU related metrics per [doc](https://grafana.com/oss/prometheus/exporters/postgres-exporter/assets/postgres_metrics_scrape.txt):

```bash
# HELP pg_settings_cpu_index_tuple_cost Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of processing each index entry during an index scan.
# TYPE pg_settings_cpu_index_tuple_cost gauge
pg_settings_cpu_index_tuple_cost{server="localhost:5432"} 0.005
# HELP pg_settings_cpu_operator_cost Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of processing each operator or function call.
# TYPE pg_settings_cpu_operator_cost gauge
pg_settings_cpu_operator_cost{server="localhost:5432"} 0.0025
# HELP pg_settings_cpu_tuple_cost Sets the planner's estimate of the cost of processing each tuple (row).
# TYPE pg_settings_cpu_tuple_cost gauge
pg_settings_cpu_tuple_cost{server="localhost:5432"} 0.01
```

We think the CPU usage could be calculated by:

```
avg by (server) (avg_over_time(pg_settings_cpu_index_tuple_cost[2m]) + avg_over_time(pg_settings_cpu_tuple_cost[2m]) + avg_over_time(pg_settings_cpu_operator_cost[2m]) ) * 100
```

We have no idea whether if the above calculation is correct or not. Could someone help us to double-check it? Or anything are we missing?

Comment: I think you are confused. Those are configuration settings not activity measures. Host CPU usage would be from the node exporter - is that what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make it time-bound, then you can use it this way:

```
(pg_settings_cpu_index_tuple_cost + pg_settings_cpu_tuple_cost + 
pg_settings_cpu_operator_cost) * 100
```